# What happens if I shift beyond the maximum ranges?

Tags: shifter

I have a sensah empire 2*11 speed brifters + front / rear derailleur. I noticed that when switching to gear -1 or 3 for the front derailleur / 12 for the rear derailleur, it makes a louder than normal clicking noise, but can't tell if something is getting damaged or not. The gears don't actually shift since -1, 3, 12 don't exist. Is there some sort of mechanism in the shifter to know when it can't go any further? Is it just the weakest component (shifter, cable, derailleur) giving up first?

EDIT: for anyone curious, apparently this is a sram failsafe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sensah shifters are based, to my knowledge, on SRAM DoubleTap designs. At maximum cable pull (first gear) SRAM shifters make a kind of snappy click noise when you try to downshift again (past the maximum cable pull). If you watch the internal mechanism when this happens, you can see the ratchet moves up a little but has no groove to slip into and goes back to the last position. It is designed as such and you won't damage it. The noise (different to the normal click) alerts you to the fact you can't make the pedalling any easier.

The above assumes Sensah have taken as much care as SRAM in the design, and not changed this principle.

Comment: https://youtu.be/q6Q15IlhjPw?t=398 shifter internals

Comment: Does it also make a unique sound when there are no harder gears left to shift to?

Comment: It isn't so noticable for the harder gears, but the release phase of the double tap motion obviously has nothing to activate in the highest/hardest (rear) gear so the lever motion won't sound the same or feel the same as any of the other gears.

Comment: nice. no damage as well?

Comment: It sounds like normal use to me, no damage

Answer (score 1):

On the rear, there is a screw to adjust for the smallest cog position, so nothing happens when shifting more into "minus" that you can do if the cable tension is wrongly adjusted (still "means" the smallest cog).

You can even have multiple negative gears, all mean the smallest cog. The existence of these gears means you need to add tension to the cable.

As for "above", the chain just jumps away from the cogs but with proper adjustment it should not go there.

I do not know much about the front derailleur.